# PhpMyAdmin does not list a database I have access to

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, connection

When I start phpMyAdmin, it does not list a database I have access too.
I know that the db exists and that I have access too, because its is the database used by one of my Joomla site.

I picked up the credential from my joomla configuration to the config.inc.php file.

Here is the file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'SQL9_MODULES';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'sql9.modules';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'xxxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yyy';

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
```

I tried as mentionned in other post this command :

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `Database` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
```

The results is empty.

I have also started the "Synchronize" function from my joomla database to my joomla database and **pma found all the tables** !!!!

The I tried to write some selects directly on the tables but I got a

```
#1046 - No database selected
```

Last remark, this is shared hosting, so I cannot connect as root to grand me some extra privileges !!

Thanks for your help

MySQL version : 5.1.66-0+squeeze1-log - (Debian)
phpMyAdmin version : 3.5.3

Update:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER
```

gives

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'xxxx'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*****************'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `xxxx`.* TO 'xxxx'@'%'
```

Any missing grants ?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version? Which MySQL version? The value you put for 'host' looks weird, are you sure that this is the correct hostname?

Comment: MySQL version : 5.1.66-0+squeeze1-log - (Debian) phpMyAdmin version : 3.5.3

Comment: Please try 'mysqli' for the extension parameter.

Comment: I've set it like this `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli'`
but it didn't change anything

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the host configured in Joomla is the same than the one configured in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: `var $dbtype = 'mysql';`
`var $host = 'sql9.modules';`
`var $user = 'xxxx';`
`var $db = '806282-1';` 
`var $session_handler = 'database';`
`var $password = 'yyy';`
The only difference I can see, is that in the joomla config I say to which db I want to connect. While with phpMyAdmin I didn't find how to specify/force a db to connect to be default. May be is it a question of grants to list the database I have access too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from my ISP support. Needed to add the following line in the configuration:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db'] = 'my-database';
```

Now it works.